# Django Server Structure and Conventions

Tags: django, deployment, fabric

I'm interested in figuring out the best practice way of organising Django apps on a server.

- Where do you place Django code?  The (old now) Almanac says /home/django/domains/somesitename.com/ but I've also seen things placed in /opt/apps/somesitename/ .  I'm thinking that the /opt/ idea sounds better as it's not global, but I've not seen opt before, and presumably it might be better for apps to go in a site specific deployer users home dir.
- Would you recommend having one global deployer user, one user per site, or one per site-env (eg, sitenamelive, sitenamestaging).  I'm thinking one per site.
- How do you version your config files?  I currently put them in an /etc/ folder at top level of source control.  eg, /etc/nginc/somesite-live.conf.
- How do you do provision your servers and do the deployment?  I've resisted Chef and Puppet for years on the hope of something Python based.  Silver Lining doesn't seem ready yet, and I have big hopes for Patchwork (https://github.com/fabric/patchwork/).  Currently we're just using some custom Fabric scripts to deploy, but the "server provisioning" is handled by a bash script and some manual steps for adding keys and creating users.  I'm about to investigate Silk Deployment (https://bitbucket.org/btubbs/silk-deployment) as it seems closest to our setup.

Thanks!

Comment: This will probably be closed as there are really 4 questions here. I keep everything simple and have all my sites under `/sites/www.mysite.com/`. Within the particular site's folder, I have a `project` folder which contains *everything* particular to that site that needs to be checked in to VCS including configuration, settings, readme's, requirements etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think there would have to be more information on what kinds of sites you are deploying: there would be differences based on the relations between the sites, both programatically and 'legally' (as in a business relation):

- Having an system account per 'site' can be handy if the sites are 'owned' by different people - if you are a web designer or programmer with a few clients, then you might benefit from separation.
- If your sites are related, i.e. a forum site, a blog site etc, you might benefit from a single deployment system (like ours).
- for libraries, if they're hosted on reputable sources (pypy, github etc), its probably ok to leave them there and deploy from them - if they're on dodgy hosts which are up or down, we take a copy and put them in a /thirdparty folder in our git repo.

**FABRIC**
Fabric is amazing - if its setup and configured right for you:

- We have a policy here which means nobody ever needs to log onto a server (which is *mostly* true - there are occasions where we want to look at the raw nginx log file, but its a rarity).
- We've got fabric configured so that there are individual functional blocks (restart_nginx, restart_uwsgi etc), but also
- higher level 'business' functions which run all the little blocks in the right order - for us to update all our servers we meerly type 'fab -i secretkey live deploy' - the live sets the settings for the live servers, and deploy ldeploys (*the -i is optional if you have your .ssh keys set up right*)
- We even have a control flag that if the live setting is used, it will ask 'are you sure' before performing the deploy.

**Our code layout**

So our code base layout looks a bit like this:

```
/         <-- folder containing readme file etc
/bin/     <-- folder containing nginx & uwsgi binaries (!)
/config/  <-- folder containing nginx config and pip list but also things like pep8 and pylint configs 
/fabric/  <-- folder containing fabric deployment
/logs/    <-- holding folder that nginx logs get written into (but not committed)
/src/     <-- actual source is in here!
/thirdparty/ <-- third party libs that we didn't trust the hosting of for pip
```

Possibly controversial because we load our binaries into our repo, but it means that if i upgrade nginx on the boxes, and want to roll back, i just do it by manipulation of git. I know what works against what build.

**How our deploy works:**

All our source code is hosted on a private bitbucket repo (we have a lot of repos and a few users, thats why bitbucket is better for us then github). We have a user account for the 'servers' with its own ssh key for bitbucket.

Deploy in fabric performs the following on each server:

- irc bot announce beginning into the irc channel
- git pull
- pip deploy (from a pip list in our repo)
- syncdb
- south migrate
- uwsgi restart
- celery restart
- irc bot announce completion into the irc channel
- start availability testing
- announce results of availability testing (and post report into private pastebin)

The 'availability test' (think unit test, but against live server) - hits all the webpages and API's on the 'test' account to make sure it gets back sane data without affecting live stats.

We also have a backup git service so if bitbucket is down, it falls over to that gracefully, and we even have jenkins integration that on a commit to the 'deploy' branch, it causes the deployment to go through

**The scary bit**

Because we use cloud computing and expect a high throughput, our boxes auto spawn. Theres a default image which contains a a copy of the git repo etc, but invariably it will be out of date, so theres a startup script which does a deployment to itself, meaning new boxes added to the cluster are automatically up-to-date.